# Angular: how to encode URL data that includes slashes by using $stateProvider?

Tags: angularjs, url

I try to send data over params by using `$stateProvider`.

This is my configuration:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('notes-empty', {
                url: '/notes',
                templateUrl: 'notes.html'
            })
    .state('notes', {
                url: '/notes/:meeting_data',
                templateUrl: 'notes.html'
            })
```

The problem is if `meeting-data` contains `/`, it brakes the state, for example:

`https://localsrc.meeter.me/gadget.html#/notes/Asia`        // OK
   `https://localsrc.meeter.me/gadget.html#/notes/Asia%2FJer`  // WRONG

*Asia%2FJer = Asia/Jer*

I tried to encode it with `var str = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(str))` but `$stateProvider` detects `/` in encoded string and tries to redirect to wrong state

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a regex syntax like this:

```
.state('notes', {
   url: '/notes/{meeting_data:.*}',
   templateUrl: 'notes.html'
})
```

Check it at [URL Routing](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing)